# Need help setting up hasMany model relationship for nested JSON and showing data in grid - EXTJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I am getting some search results back from Elastic in this format

```
{
  "took": 267,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1911,
    "max_score": 29.118078,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myIndex",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "27c9d14495f7732c6756f0d2688874f",
        "_score": 21.179974,
        "_source": {
          "file": {
            "filename": "file1.pdf"
          },
          "content": "samplecontent"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myIndex",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "27c9d14495f7732c6756f0d2688874f",
        "_score": 21.179974,
        "_source": {
          "file": {
            "filename": "file2.pdf"
          },
          "content": "samplecontent"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myIndex",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "27c9d14495f7732c6756f0d2688874f",
        "_score": 21.179974,
        "_source": {
          "file": {
            "filename": "file3.pdf"
          },
          "content": "samplecontent"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and would like to display the hits.total (1911) in the header of my grid for example, and hits.hits._source.file.filename and hits.hits._source.content in my grid.  I believe I need to setup a hasMany/belongsTo model but am a bit confused by any documentation/examples that I've found as to how to setup that relationship, as well as pick and choose those nested fields to display in the grid.  Any help or clarification would be appreciated

My store is defined as

```
Ext.define('search.store.results', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.results',

    model: 'search.model.hits',

    autoLoad: false,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://myServer:9200/_search',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'hits'
        }
    }
});
```

And my models are defined as

base

```
Ext.define('search.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    schema: {
        namespace: 'search.model'
    }
});
```

hits

```
Ext.define('search.model.hits', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'total', type: 'number'}
    ],
    hasMany:{
        model: 'hit',
        name: 'hit'
    }
});
```

hit

```
Ext.define('search.model.hit', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: '_source', type: 'source'}
    ]
});
```

source

```
Ext.define('search.model.source', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'file', type: 'file'},
        {name: 'content', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

and file

```
Ext.define('search.model.file', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'filename', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

however when I load my page I get these errors right off the bat

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.field.source
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.field.file
```

UPDATE:  This is what the results look like if I change my models to use 'reference' instead of hasMany

```
Ext.define('search.model.hits', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'total', type: 'number'},
        {name: 'hits', reference: 'hit'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('search.model.hit', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: '_source', reference: 'source'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('search.model.source', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'file', reference: 'file'},
        {name: 'content', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('search.model.file', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'filename', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

My store 'load' listener shows this information, broken into separate data structures instead of all being under the 'data' structure where the arrow is (where I'm used to finding my store records)

[image]

UPDATE #2:
If I modify my 'hits' model to use hasMany but leave the rest using 'reference' it appears to work as far as grouping my data properly in the records - now I just need to know how to display the nested results in a grid

```
Ext.define('search.model.hits', {
    extend: 'search.model.Base',

    fields: [
        {name: 'total', type: 'number'}
    ],
    hasMany:{
        model: 'hit',
        name: 'hit'
    }
});
```

produces

[image]

Comment: just wondering why you do not use ``reference: 'file'``

Comment: No reason, other than when I searched for how to load nested JSON the examples seemed to indicate that I needed to use hasMany.  I'll edit my post and show what it looks like when I use 'reference' - it doesn't put the array of 'hits' in the normal data structure where the arrow is, but instead separates each of the models/references into it's own structure which I think means it's not associating all of the data properly.

Comment: oh yes, there are two different ways to achieve association. do u think it makes seans to use ``type: search.model.file`` instead of ``type:file``